# how do i resolve this error: Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../view/file_upload which falls outside of the project src/ directory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

i'm trying to link my view/ file_upload.jsx to my react TableRow.js but it wont allow me to do that. This is what i get in the browser:

```
Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../view/file_upload which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
```

How do i get my server function that is linked to my views/File_upload.jsx to show the content(form ) in my TableRow.js via

This is my server.js

```
const multer = require('multer')
var path = require("path");

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jsx');
app.engine('jsx', require('express-react-views').createEngine());

//multer storage
var multerStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, path.join(__dirname, 'my_uploads'));
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, Date.now() + '_' + file.originalname);
  }
});

//for single file upload
var multerSingleUpload = multer({ storage: multerStorage }); 

//base index route
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  const uploadStatus = req.app.locals.uploadStatus;
  req.app.locals.uploadStatus= null;
  res.render('file_upload',{
    title:'file has been uploaded via node!',
    uploadStatus : uploadStatus
  });
});

//route for single file upload
app.post("/singleFile", multerSingleUpload.single("singleImage"), function(req, res) {
  const file = req.file
  if (!file) {
    return res.end("Please choose file to upload");
  }
  req.app.locals.uploadStatus = true;
  res.redirect('/');
})
```

My file_upload.jsx

```
var React = require('react');

function FileUpload(props) {
  return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div class='col-md-5'>
                <form action="/singleFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                    <p>Upload image</p>
                    <input type="file" id="singleImage" name="singleImage" required>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
                </input>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};

module.exports = FileUpload;
```

I am importing it like this: import FileUpload from '../../../view/file_upload'; and in my return i import it like this: , That's when it gives me the error.

Comment: You might probably have a `webpack.config.js` file with a `ModuleScopePlugin` listed in webpack plugins. That's what making it throw `Attempt to import ...` error.

Answer (score 0):

You must move your file inside the `src` directory. I'm guessing you're using `create-react-app`. It doesn't allow imports outside `src`.

Comment: but will that not effect the path from the server side?